# Show No Records Message in Google Table Charts

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I am Using Google Table Charts , I want To show No Data Message If The Rows Are Empty In The Table.
 For Example

```
   google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['table'] });
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
   function drawExternalTable(Json) {
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
   data.addColumn('number', '# of users');
   data.addColumn('number', '# of Docs');
   //data.addrow()
   var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
     table.draw(data, { showRowNumber: true });
```

Expected Output :

```
Name        #of Users         #of Docs
---------------------------------------
No Records To Display
```